# Is there a MySQL function to 'use existing value' during update?

Tags: php, mysql

**Is there a way with MySQL to specify "use previous / inherit / no change / existing value"?**

Rather than needing to pull the current data from the database and use it, or have a customized database function excluding editing those columns.

```
if(x > y) {
$role_id = 3;
} else {
$role_id = '#no-change'; // Is there a way to do this? (not proper SQL syntax)
}

$update_user = $this->db->update('users', 
array(
    'first_name'      =>  filterName($post['first_name']),
    'last_name'      =>  filterName($post['last_name']),
    'email'     =>  filterEmail($post['email']),
    'role_id'     =>  $role_id,
), $user_id_to_edit, 'user_id');
```

In a case like this where the db function is using prepared statements (not shown) I can't use the column name as to reflect the current value.

Is there such a MySQL function / variable that will essentially "ignore" updating that column? (just leave the existing value)

**UPDATE:** Here's the Update function:

```
    public function update($table, $data, $where_id, $column = 'user_id') {
        // Check for $table or $data not set
        if (( empty( $table ) || empty( $data )) || empty($data) ) {
            return false;
        }
        // Initiate variable to append to
        $placeholders ='';
        // Parse data for column and placeholder names
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $placeholders .= sprintf('%s=:%s,', $key, $key);
        }

        // Trim excess commas
        $placeholders = rtrim($placeholders, ',');

        // Append where ID to $data
        $data['where_id'] = $where_id;

        // Prepary our query for binding
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE {$table} SET {$placeholders} WHERE $column = :where_id");

        // Execute the query
        $stmt->execute($data);

        // Check for successful insertion
        if ( $stmt->rowCount() ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you selectively build the array keys / values you are passing based on whether the values have been passed?

Comment: That's how I have it currently; but it makes for seemingly redundant code; I was wondering if there was a way to avoid it. (What I've shown is a simplified version.)

Comment: It depends on the definition of `$this->db->update()`. If your function supports that, then yes. If not, then obviously not. If you're asking for the SQL syntax  to not update a specific column, then I could show you that.

Comment: I've added the update() function.

Comment: Ah. That's kind of what I thought you were doing. My answer should work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$data = array(
    'first_name'      =>  filterName($post['first_name']),
    'last_name'      =>  filterName($post['last_name']),
    'email'     =>  filterEmail($post['email']))

if(x > y) {
   $data['role_id'] = 3;
}

$update_user = $this->db->update('users', $data, $user_id_to_edit, 'user_id');
```

That way, you can customize `$data` before hand if you like.

I should also mention, if you're concerned about redundancy, you can put your data sanitation inside a function. Something along the lines of:

```
function sanitize($data) {
   if(x > y) {
      $data['role_id'] = 3;
   } else {
      if(isset($data['role_id']) {
         unset($data['role_id']);
      }
   }

   return $data;
}

$data = array(
    'first_name'      =>  filterName($post['first_name']),
    'last_name'      =>  filterName($post['last_name']),
    'email'     =>  filterEmail($post['email']))


$update_user = $this->db->update('users', sanitize($data), $user_id_to_edit, 'user_id');
```

**Edit:** Something I should mention is that, if we're talking pure SQL, all you need to do is omit those columns from the query, so:

```
UPDATE table SET Col1=val1, Col2=val2, Col3=val3 WHERE id=val
```

But if for some reason you don't want to update Col3, just remove it from the query:

```
UPDATE table SET Col1=val1, Col2=val2 WHERE id=val
```

Since you have a function that just adds whatever you give it, you just need to sanitize the data ahead of time. That's probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Doesn't directly answer my question (as far as unique SQL syntax, but it's a good workaround suggestion. I'll accept as the answer.

Comment: @BeninCA Added SQL syntax explanation too.